# React.SFC gives Element vs ReactElement<any> error, ValidationMap

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When using React.SFC, typescript gives the following error:

```
Type '({ children }: { children?: ReactNode; }) => Element' is not 
assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{}>'.
 Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any>'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | ComponentClass<any> | StatelessComponent<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<any, any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.
    Type 'ComponentClass<any>' is not assignable to type 'string | ComponentClass<any, any> | StatelessComponent<any>'.
      Type 'ComponentClass<any>' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<any>'.
        Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.
          Type 'React.ValidationMap<any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jbernal/Documents/projects/BoostMobileUI/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index").ValidationMap<any> | undefined'.
            Type 'React.ValidationMap<any>' is not assignable to type 'import("/Users/jbernal/Documents/projects/BoostMobileUI/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index").ValidationMap<any>'.
              Index signatures are incompatible.
                Type '((object: any, key: string, componentName: string, ...rest: any[]) => Error | null) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<any>'.
                  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Validator<any>'.
```

This is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import './Sidebar.scss';

export const Sidebar: React.SFC = ({ children }) => (
  <aside className="sidebar">
   {children}
  </aside>
);
```

I am also getting ValidationMap issues elsewhere, for example, when passing in this type of component into Material's react-ui library as a child of Tooltip.

Comment: I get no error with TypeScript 3.0.1 and `@types/react` 16.4.11.  What version of TypeScript and `@types/react` are you using?

Comment: I am using Typescript 3.0.1 in VSCode and the same react types you mentioned. 16.4.11. I have TS installed globally and the package.json has `"typescript": "^3.0.1",`

Does tslint-react, tslint, or tslint-loader impact any of these issues?

Comment: Note: this error does not show up using TS 2.8.3

Comment: Then the problem is probably related to the `LibraryManagedAttributes` feature added in TypeScript 3.0.1, but downgrading TypeScript is not a good solution.  First make sure you don't have two copies of the `@types/react` folder: search your project directory and any `node_modules` in ancestor directories.  If that isn't it, then I'm out of guesses, but if you can publish a repository that reproduces the problem, I will look.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that as a solution!

Comment: So it turns out that when I used 2.8.3, the issue was still present (just hadn't reloaded all the way so I wasn't seeing it the first time).

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too and came here looking for an answer.

Turns out, I was working on a yarn workspaces monorepo and there were multiple `node_modules` using different versions of `@types/react`.

Here what solved the issue for me:

- Make all dependencies point to the same version at each `package.json`;
- Delete all the `node_modules` folders (maybe delete the `yarn.lock` file too);
- Run `yarn install`